# Microsoft Blend manual for VS2012 and/or VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blend

I've searched for a good and complete manual on Blend for Visual Studio 2012 and/or 2013 for developing WPF Application with C#, but I still haven't found anything.

Do you know a complete and well-made manual to learn this software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tutorial about design. For Windows 8 or Window phone 8 or WPF are the same basically.

http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/designing-your-xaml-ui-with-blend-jump-start#?fbid=5WqBAoX8Aog

I suggest you to see more about Jerry Nixon videos.
http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/01/the-most-comprehensive-blend-for-visual.html